# webView Android app

Tags: java, android, webview

To the code below using webView, is there any way to enter the site without typing the entire URL (www.google.com)? Currently need to enter the URL completely (http://www.google.com.br).

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editText;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewlayout);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
}

public void abrirPagina (View v){
    String url = editText.getText().toString();
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean overrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl"); is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to examine `url` and add additional information to it, through string concatenation, if needed. For example, you might see if it `startsWith()` either `http://` or `https://`, then add `http://` or `https://` yourself if needed.

IOW, this is not the job of `WebView`, but the job of the program handing the URL to `WebView`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just one more question, one of the buttons, put the data "webView.loadUrl (" http://www.ustream.tv/nasahdtv ");" to access directly by clicking the button. This url directs to a streaming of NasaTV. When I open the application, it is just loading and does not open. Some allowance for this type of task is necessary? @CommonsWare

Comment: @LuizHenriqueUgliano: I have not tried to view streaming media in a `WebView`, sorry.